# Deleted __pycache__ and __init__.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

- Django 1.6
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Python 3.2.3

Accidentally deleted a Django app's `__pycache__` folder & its `__init__.py` file, and it crashed Django. when I `python3 manage.py runserver`, it'll instantly claims there's no module by the name *agepct* even though the app's directory exists and all files are in it (except the ones I deleted). I emptied the trash so I can't get the files back. Is there any way to get the app working again short of recreating the whole app from scratch?

Here's the traceback it spits out when I try to `runserver`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/__init__.py", line 124, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 824, in _gcd_import
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name))
ImportError: No module named agepct
```

Comment: The `__init__.py` file would not have been in the `__pycache__` directory, but in the `agepct` directory. Re-create that file there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__pycache__` directory is a cache for byte-compiled files and will be re-built when you import the package.

The `__init__.py` file on the other hand is what makes a directory a module. If it was initially empty, simply recreate it in the `agepct` directory for the imports to work again. Note that `__init__.py` would *not* have been inside the `__pycache__` directory.

If `__init__.py` was more than just an empty 'make this a package' file, then you have to recreate that code from scratch or restore the file from a backup.

Comment: aahhh ok, I see now. I learned about these files when I 1st began learning Python and just never thought much about them since. So I was confoozled trying to make the app work again. Thanks!